# En dash cause error when Import data using load data in file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

we are using load data infile

```
$this->db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' 
INTO TABLE excel_details 
CHARACTER SET  utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(Email,name,address) 
SET cid =".$cid.", csvsheet_id=".$csvsheet_id
);
```

string contain en dash cause 1300 error 
address contain 2–5

Comment: Can you show us the exact content of `$file_path` ?

Comment: your query starts with `("LOAD ...` and ends with `(Email));` did you forget to close double quotes, typo or ..?

Comment: `(Email,name,address) // address content 2–5` Are `//` allowed as comments in MySQL? Try to use `#` instead

Comment: @kerbholz # comments are used in python. sql comments starts with `--`

Comment: @Cid Then they need to update their documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html ;)

Comment: Ah this might be specific to MySQL then

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid SQL `(Email,name,address) // address content 2–5`. If you want to comment in SQL, you have to use `--` for single line comment or `/* */` for multiline.